# Lost Root privelages in MariaDB 10.6

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So I can't even remember how this happened, I believe I was worried about how running

```
mysql -u root
```

Was allowing the root user to login without a password or even asking for one...

So I went down a rabbit hole and ran these codes like an idiot:

```
USE mysql;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS user;
CREATE VIEW user AS SELECT * FROM mysql.global_priv;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Once I ran that, everything was gone. I can't do anything with the root user other then access MariaDB in general (mysql -u root), but I'm not able to do anything. Running this causes an error saying I don't have the permissions to execute:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  *.* to 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I have tried everyhing... --skip-grant-tables, safe mode, etc - same errors and no results...

It seems like the mysql.user table is missing from what I could find too...

Let me know if there is any hope, or maybe I'll just have to re-install somehow

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I ended up backing up all my databases from cPanel backups, then uninstalled and re-installed MariaDB

Was much faster than myself messing around and waiting for an answer :/

Thank you